# Why is pyplot.imshow() changing color channels in arrays

Tags: opencv, numpy, image-processing, matplotlib

For the life of me I have been struggling with this for the last 24 hours.  I am doing a Neural Net--storing images in a 4D-array.  The first index of the array is bascially the "sample" aka sample 1,2,3, etc.  dimenions 2,3,4 are 128x128 x3 rgb pictures.  Now in the process of this, i take the input pictures (which are not 128x128) and rescale them.  But when I picked a sample, it had all the color channels mixed up.  So I tried to figure out where the problem was.

If I just resize the picture and assign the nummber array (128x128x3) to a variable, everything is 'normal'.  If I assign the 'sub-array' to the larger 4-d array the color channels get mixed up.  However I can recover the original by picture subtracting the array-slice for the sameple from 255.

Here is a code snippet with the original(1), resized(2), color-channel mix(3), recovered (4).

I know the open cv and pyplot.imshow() use different color channels, but the fact that it appears that storing the picture in the larger array is what causes the switch-- that is confusing me.  Some guidance would be appreciated.

Also I can "subtratct" the arrays (img2-train[0]) and get an array of all zeros).  That part REALLY is confusing.  They are the same numbers and yet imshow() gives 2 completely different images.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread(<path to your pic>)
img2 = cv2.resize(img, (128, 128))
train = np.ndarray(shape=(1,128, 128,3))
plt.subplot(1,4,1)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.subplot(1,4,2)
plt.imshow(img2)
plt.subplot(1,4,3)
train[0] = img2
plt.imshow(train[0])
plt.subplot(1,4,4)
plt.imshow(255-train[0])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok--this was strange.  It turns out when I was putting the data into a 4-d array Matplotlib was for some reason scaling the data differently.  To recover my original image in #3 all i had to do was divide by 255.  I figured this out by an educated 'guess' when reviewing the imshow() documents which said that data was scaled to between 0 and 1.  Since all my data was between 0 and 255, i scaled it 'manually'.  Odd behavior, but when feeding a neural net, you want to make sure your data is not somehow getting 'tweaked'

The 'fix' for the third plot is then just:

```
plt.subplot(1,4,3)
train[0] = img2
plt.imshow(train[0]/255)
```

Comment: wow, this was it. I can't hardly fathom how the image can even look halfway decent if it's scaled by 255.  I need to understand what happened here.... please give a link if you know.

Answer (score 8):

`OpenCV` stores color images using the `BGR` convention while
`matplotlib` uses the `RGB` convention.

You should simply flip the channels order when displaying the images using `pyplot`:

```
 plt.imshow(img[:,:,[2,1,0])
 plt.imshow(train[0][:,:,[2,1,0])
 ...
```

Alternatively you can use `cv2.imshow`

Comment: Reversing the channels doesn't give back the original image.  If you compare the second and 3rd images, they are the same set of numbers (if you subtract them, you get zero).  I get a third "off color" image by reversing the color channels (train[0,:,:,::-1)